# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar nombres de carpetas en php?

Tags: php, funciones

Hay alguna funcion o algo para ocultar nombres de carpetas en php ?

Por ejemplo quiero ocultar la carpeta controller:

localhost/students/controller/edit_student.php?id=15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para bloquear tanto la indexación como el acceso, se utiliza el Archivo.htaccess

Como en este post en inglés de [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess) tienes que añadir el archivo si no lo tienes, y lo configuras dependiendo de los accesos o permisos que quieras dar.

Aquí te dejo la documentación con ejemplos de archivos ya configurados
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/

Puedes bloquear todos los accesos a carpetas con

```
Deny from all
```

O puedes hacer un redirect a tu 404

```
Redirect /includes/ 404.html
```

Comment: Podrías enriquecer la respuesta añadiendo el código que se pone en .htaccess, para no tener que ir a verlo al sitio de al lado :D

Comment: Podrías dar las instrucciones de cómo hacer el redirect? Y poner un ejemplo si no es mucho pedir.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar la respuesta de Guillermo, en Nginx la restricción a un directorio se hace añadiendo un `prefix location` en el archivo de vhost. En tu caso:

```
location /students/controller/ {
  deny all;
  return 403;
}
```

Si además quisieras restringir el acceso a todo el contenido del directorio, se haría con una expresión regular

```
location ^~ /students/controller/ {
  deny all;
  return 403;
}
```

Comment: Te me has adelantado, no podía y ahora la iba a ampliar ;)

Comment: Pero yo no uso nginx !

Comment: Pero alguien puede buscar en google con el título de tu pregunta y llegar a este hilo. Añadí el caso nginx pensando en ese alguien, que a lo mejor no es tan improbable.